# printing the output vertically in xpath python

Tags: python, csv, xpath, screen-scraping

```
import lxml
from lxml import html
import requests
import re
import csv
with open('job.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    a=csv.writer(csvfile)
    a.writerow(["title","employer","salary","location"])
    for i in range(1):
        url = "http://www.jobs-salary.com/salaries.php?q=illumina&ml=25&lc=&state=&company=&title=&sb=relevance&ps={}".format(i)
        page = requests.get(url)
        # print page.text
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
        for item in tree.xpath('//table[@class="resTb"]'):

        # print tree.xpath('//table[@class="resTb"]//td/b/a/text()')
        info = {}
        info['title']=item.xpath('.//td/b/a/text()')
        h = info['title']
        print h
```

the output which i am getting is

`['Scientist I', 'Scientist', 'Scientist', 'Scientist', 'Biochemist', 'Scientist I', 'Biochemist', 'Scientist I', 'Scientist I', 'Biomedical Engineer', 'Biochemist', 'Fluidics Engineer', 'Biochemist And Biophysicists', 'Scientist I', 'Scientist I', 'Scientist', 'Scientist', 'Scientist I', 'Scientist I', 'Scientist II']`

but i want it vertically with no brackets and commas
can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to simply output your list as a string that is separated by a newline (\n). You can do this by calling `join` on your list `h`:

```
h = ['Scientist I', 'Scientist', 'Scientist', 'Scientist', 'Biochemist', 'Scientist I', 'Biochemist', 'Scientist I', 'Scientist I', 'Biomedical Engineer', 'Biochemist', 'Fluidics Engineer', 'Biochemist And Biophysicists', 'Scientist I', 'Scientist I', 'Scientist', 'Scientist', 'Scientist I', 'Scientist I', 'Scientist II']
print('\n'.join(h))
```

Output:

```
Scientist I
Scientist
Scientist
Scientist
Biochemist
Scientist I
Biochemist
Scientist I
Scientist I
Biomedical Engineer
Biochemist
Fluidics Engineer
Biochemist And Biophysicists
Scientist I
Scientist I
Scientist
Scientist
Scientist I
Scientist I
Scientist II
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of itearting a table, iterate each row (`tr` inside the `table`). And find `td`s there.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import csv

url = "http://www.jobs-salary.com/salaries.php?q=illumina&ml=25&relevance&ps={}"
with open('job.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    a = csv.writer(csvfile)
    a.writerow(["title", "employer", "salary", "location"])
    for i in range(1):
        page = requests.get(url.format(i))
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
        for item in tree.xpath('//table[@class="resTb"]/tr')[1:]:
            row = [
                item.xpath('.//td[1]')[0].text_content(),  # title
                item.xpath('.//td[2]')[0].text_content(),  # employer
                item.xpath('.//td[3]')[0].text_content(),  # salary
                item.xpath('.//td[4]')[0].text_content(),  # location
            ]
            print row
            a.writerow(row)
```